# Ruby on Rails retrieve datetime by converting it from UTC to user's time zone from database by querying date

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

my application stores attendance datetime from user as 2014-11-23 08:42:00 by converting it to UTC, application has custom search method to search attendance only by entering date as 2014-11-23.
Now problem is i have 5 attendance of date 2014-11-23 with different time and Rails stored it by converting into UTC. so for 2 record it is converted and date is changed to 2014-11-22.

my search query is 2014-11-23 and expected result is all 5 records but getting only 3.
not getting other 2 because they are converted to 2014-11-22

How to get all 5 records only with entering 2014-11-23 ?
Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you store the datetime you can use it for that query using `beginning_of_day` and `end_of_day` methods on the time with timezone

```
date = Time.parse('Wed, 19 Nov 2014 19:23:59 UTC +00:00')
# => 2014-11-19 19:23:59 UTC
d = date.in_time_zone('Paris')
# => Wed, 19 Nov 2014 20:23:59 CET +01:00


User.where(created_at: (d.beginning_of_day..d.end_of_day)).count
#   (46.5ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "users"  WHERE ("users"."created_at" BETWEEN '2014-11-18 23:00:00.000000' AND '2014-11-19 22:59:59.999999')
```

Comment: its not giving expected results, i want to retrieve only by date (eg. 2014-11-23) from db after conversion to specified time_zone.

Comment: it is working with .where but Actually i have it in ':conditions' and with ':conditions' it is not working..please help

Comment: What version of Rails are you using? I think since Rails 3.2 `where` is the preferred way to build queries.

Comment: i am using Rails 3.2.8, my search function has multiple search criteria and doing search/retrieve data by 'AND'ing all criteria so used :conditions with scoped joins...can we do anything with this ?

Comment: With reference to your suggestion i did a trick may be which is not recommended, by taking 'sql' of 'User.where(created_at: (d.beginning_of_day..d.end_of_day))' and picking substring of SQL statement & using in my query of :conditions It worked for me :) thanks.